# Substitute for flaked coconut

Tags: baking

I would like to bake an Italian Cream Cake. Most recipes call for sweetened flaked coconut and a few shredded coconut.

I readily have fresh grated coconut and dessicated coconut. Can either of these be used in place of sweetened flaked   without significantly altering the cake texture / moisture?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22651/can-i-make-sweetened-coconut-from-dried-coconut

Answer (score 1):

Grated coconut will probably be your best bet. However you will need to add a tiny bit of sugar so the taste is not thrown out of proportion.